# Build succeeds but content doesn't appear when running

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

When I am running Xcode with below codes it says "build succeeded" but on the simulator nothing is being appeared and I don't know why. Please kindly advise what to fix.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let numberOfPlanets = 8
    let diameterOfEarth = 24859.92 // in miles, where pole to pol


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        print("Welcome to solar system!")
        print("There are \(numberOfPlanets) to explore")
        print("You are currenly on the Earth, which has a circumstance of \(diameterOfEarth) miles")

        firstTextView.text = "Welcome to solar system!"


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var firstTextView: UITextView!

}
```

added.
thank you Shades [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wwLe.jpg)for your advice. I checked all you advised but the console is not still printing. I changed the name of "ViewController.swift" to "main.swift" to remove an error saying "expressions are not at the top level". probably it is the reason? I added the screenshot of mine for better understanding. please help.

Comment: Are those lines being printed to the console?

Comment: no it is not being printed to the console neither.

Comment: check view controller in storyboard if u have selected "is intial view controller" .

Comment: if you mean the "class" in the identity inspector to check "view controller", it has been so.

Comment: I don't know how but in the new project it works.